# Some of my D3D11 objects null themselves as ComPtrs when calling certain Device Context functions

Tags: c++, directx-11

Trying to get a DX11 project up and running. Got most of the needed objects up and running for the basics of rendering, but when I call OMSetRenderTargets, or IASetVertexBuffers, the objects I pass through for those function null themselves after the function call.

All my ID3D11 objects are made using ComPtrs, and I really have no clue this happens. Any thoughts?

I've tried turning them into plain old pointers, and when passing them to said functions, they no longer stop nulling themselves. But I don't really want that as I'm trying to make them all ComPtrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are hitting with [ComPtr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/wrl/comptr-class) is quite simple: You are using `operator&` which is the same as calling `ReleaseAndGetAddressOf`.

In typical COM usage, the `operator&` is only used when creating new instances, so the mapping makes sense:

```
// wicFactory can be either a IWICFactory* or a Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IWICFactory>
// and the following code will work.

HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_WICImagingFactory,
    nullptr,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_PPV_ARG(&wicFactory));
```

In Direct3D, however, there are a number of functions that take pointers-to-COM-pointers as input arguments that are *not* object factories, such as the ones you listed in your question. In that case you should use the `Get` method or `GetAddressOf` possibly with a temporary variable:

```
context->OMSetRenderTargets(1, renderTargetView.GetAddressOf(),
    depthStencilView.Get());
```

-or-

```
auto rt = renderTargetView.Get();
context->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &rt, depthStencilView.Get());
```

And in the case of needing an array of COM-pointers that are in ComPtr:

```
ID3D11SamplerState* samplers[] = { sampler1.Get(), sampler2.Get() };
context->PSSetSamplers(0, _countof(samplers), samplers);
```

See [this wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr) for some general usage advice for ComPtr.